# Loop Vectorization 001

Tags: c++, c, optimization, vectorization, icc

I have a Vectorization optimization problem.

I have a struct pDst which have 3 fields named: 'red', 'green' and 'blue'.
The type might be 'Char', 'Short' or 'Float'.This is given and can not be altered.
Theres is another array pSrc which represents an image [RGB] - Namely an array of 3 pointers which every one of them point to a layer of an image.
Each layer is built using IPP plane oriented image (Namely, Each plane is formed independently - 'ippiMalloc_32f_C1'):
http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/ipp/ippi/ippi_ch3/functn_Malloc.html.

We would like to copy it as described in the following code:

```
for(int y = 0; y < imageHeight; ++y)
{
    for(int x = 0; x < imageWidth; ++x)
    {
        pDst[x + y * pDstRowStep].red     = pSrc[0][x + y * pSrcRowStep];
        pDst[x + y * pDstRowStep].green   = pSrc[1][x + y * pSrcRowStep];
        pDst[x + y * pDstRowStep].blue    = pSrc[2][x + y * pSrcRowStep];
    }
}
```

Yet, in this form the compiler can't vectorize the code.
At first it says:

> "loop was not vectorized: existence of vector dependence.".

When I use the  #pragma ivdep to help the compiler (Since there's no dependence) I get the following error:

> "loop was not vectorized: dereference too complex.".

Anyone has an idea how to allow vectorization?
I use Intel Compiler 13.0.
Thanks.

## Update:

If I edit the code as following:

```
Ipp32f *redChannel      = pSrc[0];
Ipp32f *greenChannel  = pSrc[1];
Ipp32f *blueChannel     = pSrc[2];
for(int y = 0; y < imageHeight; ++y)
{
    #pragma ivdep
    for(int x = 0; x < imageWidth; ++x)
    {
        pDst[x + y * pDstRowStep].red     = redChannel[x + y * pSrcRowStep];
        pDst[x + y * pDstRowStep].green   = greenChannel[x + y * pSrcRowStep];
        pDst[x + y * pDstRowStep].blue    = blueChannel[x + y * pSrcRowStep];
    }
}
```

For output types of 'char' and 'short' I get vecotization.
Yet for type of 'float' I don't.
Instead I get the following message:

> loop was not vectorized: vectorization possible but seems inefficient.

How could that be?

Comment: In its present form it won't vectorize whatever you do, since you are doing a "gather" operation here.

Comment: That's what I'm looking for, which form would allow vectorization? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following code, using pragma ivdep does surely ignore the vector dependence but the compiler heuristics/cost analysis came to a conclusion that vectorizing the loop is not efficient:

```
Ipp32f *redChannel      = pSrc[0];
Ipp32f *greenChannel  = pSrc[1];
Ipp32f *blueChannel     = pSrc[2];
for(int y = 0; y < imageHeight; ++y)
{
    #pragma ivdep
    for(int x = 0; x < imageWidth; ++x)
    {
        pDst[x + y * pDstRowStep].red     = redChannel[x + y * pSrcRowStep];
        pDst[x + y * pDstRowStep].green   = greenChannel[x + y * pSrcRowStep];
        pDst[x + y * pDstRowStep].blue    = blueChannel[x + y * pSrcRowStep];
    }
}
```

The vectorization will be inefficient since the operation involves copying contiguous block of memory from source to non-contiguous memory locations at the destination. So there is a scatter happening here. If you still want to enforce vectorization and see if there any performance improvement in comparison to non-vectorized version, please use pragma simd instead of pragma ivdep as shown below:

```
#include<ipp.h>
struct Dest{
float red;
float green;
float blue;
};
void foo(Dest *pDst, Ipp32f **pSrc, int imageHeight, int imageWidth, int pSrcRowStep, int pDstRowStep){
    Ipp32f *redChannel      = pSrc[0];
    Ipp32f *greenChannel  = pSrc[1];
    Ipp32f *blueChannel     = pSrc[2];
    for(int y = 0; y < imageHeight; ++y)
    {
        #pragma simd
        for(int x = 0; x < imageWidth; ++x)
        {
            pDst[x + y * pDstRowStep].red     = redChannel[x + y * pSrcRowStep];
            pDst[x + y * pDstRowStep].green   = greenChannel[x + y * pSrcRowStep];
            pDst[x + y * pDstRowStep].blue    = blueChannel[x + y * pSrcRowStep];
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

The corresponding vectorization report is:

```
$ icpc -c test.cc -vec-report2
test.cc(14): (col. 9) remark: SIMD LOOP WAS VECTORIZED
test.cc(11): (col. 5) remark: loop was not vectorized: not inner loop
```

More documentation on pragma simd is available at https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/514582.

Answer (score 1):

Something along those lines should work (`char` version, untested, also keep in mind that __m128i pointers should be properly aligned!)

```
void interleave_16px_to_rgb0(__m128i *red, __m128i *green, __m128i *blue, __m128i *dest) {
  __m128i zero = _mm_setzero_si128();
  __m128i rg_0 = _mm_unpackhi_epi8(*red, *green);
  __m128i rg_1 = _mm_unpacklo_epi8(*red, *green);
  __m128i bz_0 = _mm_unpackhi_epi8(*blue, zero);
  __m128i bz_1 = _mm_unpacklo_epi8(*blue, zero);
  dest[0] = _mm_unpackhi_epi16(rg_0, bz_0);
  dest[1] = _mm_unpacklo_epi16(rg_0, bz_0);
  dest[2] = _mm_unpackhi_epi16(rg_1, bz_1);
  dest[3] = _mm_unpacklo_epi16(rg_1, bz_1);
}
```

This will take 16 bytes from each plane:

```
r0 r1 r2 ... r16
g0 g1 g2 ... g16
b0 b1 b2 ... b16
```

and interleave them like so, writing out 16x4 bytes starting from `*dest`:

```
r0 g0 b0 0 r1 g1 b1 0 r2 g2 b2 0 ... r16 g16 b16 0
```

It goes without saying that you can use the same family of functions to interleave other data types as well.

---

*Update:* better yet, since you already have the IPPs, you should try to use what's provided instead of reinventing the wheel. From a quick check it appears that ippiCopy_8u_P3C3R or ippiCopy_8u_P4C4R are what you are looking for.

Comment: Yet, I'm not just trying to interleave, Pay attention to the output data structure. I don't think it is exactly as in IPP.

Comment: All I can see is an interleave with stride. What's your point?

Comment: Also, I'd love to pay attention to the output data structure. Too bad you didn't include in your question... :-P

Comment: Hi, I wrote about pDst which is a struct (Not an array, it is array of structs). It is not an array I can assume the pixels sits next to each other in memory. Only the array of structs is contiguous.

Comment: Either you're prematurely optimizing, in which case you should stop right now, or you're not. In the latter case, you're expected to be prepared to change your data structures.

Comment: The structure of the data isn't to my choice.